# python: TypeError: expected string or buffer

Tags: python

I have this code, parsing data from a website:

```
f = open('a url')
new = f.read()
derp = re.findall(r'<ol class="lh-192 trendingnow_trend-list fw-b">(.*?)</ol>', new)
line = derp

def striphtml2(data):
    p = re.compile(r'\d')
    return p.sub(' ', data)
new = striphtml2(line)
#removes anything in <>
def striphtml(data):
    p = re.compile(r'<.*?>')
    return p.sub(' ', data)
ninja = striphtml(new)
```

But every time I run it, I get this:

```
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

I don't know what is wrong with it.

Comment: And what is the *traceback* of the error?

Comment: Most of all, what is `line`?

Comment: What's the type of `data`?

Comment: umm, I don't know @MartijnPieters

Comment: Data is the information I am parsing @PauloBu,

Comment: @user2493744: That tells us nothing. What does `print type(line)` tell you `line` is?

Comment: same with line @Martijin Pieters

Comment: line is the data I am parsing. data is just the variable for the function @MartijnPieters

Comment: @user2493744: I *know* `line` is the data you are parsing. **It is not a string**. You need to show us the code that *produces* `line`.

Comment: there, thats line @MartijnPieters

Comment: @everyone The rollback was my bad. I saw all the `derp`s and thought vandalism.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing in a *list* into the function. `line` is not a string, but a whole list of strings.

Loop over it:

```
for line in derp:
```