# Expected string or buffer (in re.sub)

Tags: python

I ***have*** seen similar questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16193521/typeerror-expected-string-or-buffer), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17365893/python-typeerror-expected-string-or-buffer)) before on SO and I know that `re.sub` expects a string (which, I believe, I am providing) but I don't know what's wrong in the following code:

```
tuples = re.findall(r'id":"(.*?)".*?name":"(.*?)"', response.text, re.DOTALL)
outfile = open("badEXtsWithIDs.csv", "wb")
print "Writing into CSV"
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
for entry in tuples:
    writeName = re.sub(r'\W', " ", entry)
    writer.writerow(writeName)
```

I think that `re.sub` needs a `str` variable but, isn't entry a `str`? I get a error: `TypeError: expected string or buffer` on the line having`re.sub`. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Ya, I know (may be I am not getting what's the problem). But why would be that a problem? I am using `entry` which is a member of `tuples`..

Comment: @falsetru - Its `<type 'unicode'>`. But I don't think that would be a problem. Also I printed tuples, its all strings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you have more than one matching group, `re.findall` returns a `list` of n-`tuple`s:

```
re.findall('(foo).(bar)', 'foo foo bar foo|bar')
Out[5]: [('foo', 'bar'), ('foo', 'bar')]
```

So clearly each `entry` in `tuples` is a `tuple`.  When you pass a `tuple` to `re.sub`, well, it complains.

```
tuples = re.findall('(foo).(bar)', 'foo foo bar foo|bar')

for entry in tuples:
    re.sub('oo','ox',entry)

...
/usr/lib/python3.3/re.py in sub(pattern, repl, string, count, flags)
    168     a callable, it's passed the match object and must return
    169     a replacement string to be used."""
--> 170     return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
    171 
    172 def subn(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

So, do something else.  Maybe use `map`:

```
for entry in tuples:
    print(' '.join(map(lambda s: re.sub('oo','ox',s),entry)))

fox bar
fox bar
```

Or more readably a comprehension

```
writer.writerow([re.sub(r'\W', " ",s) for s in entry])
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks. My `entry` field only contained one value so wasn't able to understand why it happened.This helps.