# How to replace special character using regex in pyspark

Tags: python, regex, pyspark

I am trying to replace `}{` in a text file with `},{`  but I'm getting an error saying

```
return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

I am coding a spark job with python (pyspark).

Code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import re

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Usage: PythonBLEDataParser.py <file>", file=sys.stderr)
        exit(-1)

    spark = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName("PythonBLEDataParser")\
        .getOrCreate()

    toJson = spark.sparkContext.textFile("/root/vasi/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/vas_files/BLE_data_Sample.txt")
    toJson1 = re.sub("}{","},{",toJson) #i want to replace }{  with  },{
    print(toJson1)
```

Sample data:

```
{"EdgeMac":"E4956E4E4015","BeaconMac":"247189F24DDB","RSSI":-59,"MPow":-76,"Timestamp":"1486889542495633","AdData":"0201060303AAFE1716AAFE00DD61687109E602F514C96D00000001F05C0000"}
{"EdgeMac":"E4956E4E4016","BeaconMac":"247189F24DDC","RSSI":-59,"MPow":-76,"Timestamp":"1486889542495633","AdData":"0201060303AAFE1716AAFE00DD61687109E602F514C96D00000001F05C0000"}
{"EdgeMac":"E4956E4E4017","BeaconMac":"247189F24DDD,"RSSI":-59,"MPow":-76,"Timestamp":"1486889542495633","AdData":"0201060303AAFE1716AAFE00DD61687109E602F514C96D00000001F05C0000"}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21619230/expected-string-or-buffer-in-re-sub

Comment: hi @BeyhanGül could you please explain with code. Because I think in my case, as I am not using findall, resultant will not have tuples.

Answer (score 4):

Tried with dataframe instead of rdd and its working. Just placed escape character before braces

```
df_sample = spark.read.text('path/to/sample.txt')
df_sample.withColumn('value',regexp_replace(df_sample['value'],'\\}\\{','},{')).collect()[0]
```

Comment: I am getting 

    df3 = df_sample.withColumn('value',regexp_replace(df_sample['value'],'\\}\\{','},{')).collect()[0]
NameError: name 'regexp_replace' is not defined

I am  newbee, what is value here refers to ?

Comment: from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace