# Pyspark not writing correctly csv file

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

Here's how pyspark wrote my file.

Do you have any idea?

Here's the code:

```
output_file_path = '/tmp/users/csv'
df=spark.read.parquet("/user/hive/warehouse/tmp.db/users/*.parq")
df.coalesce(1).write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').mode('overwrite').option("header", "true").save(output_file_path)
```

[image]

Comment: See if the post works for you - 
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47648038/how-to-replace-special-character-using-regex-in-pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47648038/how-to-replace-special-character-using-regex-in-pyspark)

Comment: can you provide the original data on `CSV`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was, the create table statement used to generate parquet files (files that I use later when I read with dataframe), create data in binary format.
The solution is to cast all your columns to the right format (when you read it with a dataframe).
Thank you all for your help :)

Comment: The real question is why are you creating the parquet files with binary type columns

Comment: In my process, I have to create a table with impala-shell. The create table statement have the property "STORED AS PARQUET". You have to know that create table within hive/impala generate files in parquet with values stored in binary format.

Comment: This is not accurate. See my answer.

Comment: That's what I said, values are converted to string and stored as binary. My dataframe contain string, float and integer values.

Comment: No, not the same. The floats, integers and basically every other type other than  string won't need any conversion and as you see in my answer, all strings can be handled with a single parameter. No need for one-by-one conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you have not specified the `delimiter`

```
output_file_path = '/tmp/users/csv'
df=spark.read.parquet("/user/hive/warehouse/tmp.db/users/*.parq")
df.coalesce(1).write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').mode('overwrite').option("header", "true").option("delimiter",",").save(output_file_path)
```

Comment: For CSV , default delimiter is comma. Unless you want to specify of your own like '|'. This will work regardless you are specifying any delimiter.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I found the solution. I post the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It's not "values" that are being stored in binary format, it's **strings**, and there is Spark parameter to handle it.

[spark.sql.parquet.binaryAsString](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#configuration)

| Property Name | Default | Meaning | Since Version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| spark.sql.parquet.binaryAsString | false | Some other Parquet-producing systems, in particular Impala, Hive, and older versions of Spark SQL, do not differentiate between binary data and strings when writing out the Parquet schema. This flag tells Spark SQL to interpret binary data as a string to provide compatibility with these systems. | 1.1.1 |